# Terraform multiple AWS accounts configured under single remote S3 backend

Tags: terraform

We are using TF 0.12 under EC2. We are currently having 3 AWS accounts with different configurations (Dev, Sandbox, Prod) and would like to use single remote state S3 bucket with a single repo integrated with Atlantis.

At this point we are having issues in configuring TF with multiple AWS accounts. Workspace is not an option as the configuration per account is different. Either using EC2 role will not work since even though the role is going to be present on all accounts, TF will not know where to deploy. We are trying atm using assume role, but we are stuck on how exactly this should be configured.

It seems we are missing some steps in configuring it as we get Error that role cannot be assumed. Do we need to configure AWS CLI?

Expected result would be to have the 3 accounts available under TF, while switching to different directories (dev, sandbox, prod), init, plan, and apply to be working. For each account the remote state to be placed under bucket\account_type(dev, sandbox, prod).tfstate.

Comment: Why do you want to use the same backend instead of an S3 bucket in each AWS account?

Comment: To have it more organized and secured, but I guess we can use specific S3 bucket per account.

Comment: in my current organisation, we create a repository for each account and we use a remote state for each account as well, but for the resources, we use modules, so each repos has a main.tf file that includes the module we create, and we move the common resources into that module.